# Python: listing all the URLs of a website without index

Tags: python, url, web-crawler

I can access each of the following URLs individually: `http://www.example.com/{.*}.html`

However the access to the main page `http://www.example.com` is somehow restricted and I am redirected to an error page displaying: `Erreur 403 - Refus de traitement de la requête (Interdit - Forbidden)`.

Is there a way to list all the URLs of the HTML pages hosted under that domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Brian: I managed to do it starting crawling from a list of accessible HTML pages hosted under the domain.

```
# scrap.py

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/***.html'  # Accessible URL
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\.html', )), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print response.url
```

And then:

```
$ scrapy runspider scrap.py > urls.out
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. You can't just list out all of the HTML pages in that domain like you list a directory. Assuming the website's robots.txt allows it, your best bet is to crawl the website using a web crawling module, like http://scrapy.org/

Comment: I tried with `scrapy` but could not scrap any item. Got the following message: `[scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
[scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET http://www.example.com> (referer: None) ['partial']
[scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <403 http://www.example.com>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`

Comment: You can't access a forbidden site (error 403). You need to start from http://www.example.com/index.html or some other site that has a lot of links on it. Crawling will recursively go to all of the links on the website, but it still cannot access a forbidden site.